# How do I access JSON keys with same names from objects with different names?

Tags: python, json

I have a list of objects like this:

```
{
  "311243752289206293": {
    "user_id": "311243752289206293",
    "username": "Daniel",
  },
  "766430137381683201": {
    "user_id": "766430137381683201",
    "username": "Jeff",
  },
  "890423576283463690": {
    "user_id": "890423576283463690",
    "username": "Larry",
  },
```

How can I access all the user IDs if the object names differ? Is there any way to refer to all objects despite the various names?

I'd like to put these IDs in a list like this:

```py
import json

with open("coolFile.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

id_list = []
id_list.append(data['user_id']) # <--- What do I do here to access all the user_id keys from the objects with different names?
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Not 100% what you want, but likely `id_list = [val['user_id'] for val in data.values()]`

Comment: It looks like this is supposed to be an index of user_id to a user dict holding more information. It may be reasonable to do `id_list = list(data.keys())`. But then, maybe you don't need to do anything, depending on what your later intentions are. If you want to see if a user is in the data, `my_user in data` would work. If you wanted to enumerate users, `for user in data:` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a list of objects you have a dictionary.

Built-in dict class has method returning [keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), [values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) or [both (items)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

All you need to do is to iterate over the values and get user_id from each object:

```
id_list = [user["user_id"] for user in data.values()]
```